# font style not changing after adding font family in css

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

i have an html website, i am trying to change the fontfamily of a heading, i loaded the font file which is in my server and did the following code:

```css
font-family: 'Berton Voyage Regular',sans-serif"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://molugu.com/yantraev/BERTON-VOYAGE-TRIAL.TTF">
```

but still the font family is not changing, can anyone please tell me how to change the font family, thanks in advance

Comment: try ```https``` instead of ```http```. For use on modern browsers you should however look at ```woff``` types.

Comment: @prettyInPink tried bro, not working

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? What happens when you set font-family to ```'Berton Voyage'```, without including Regular.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try to remove the quote at the end? - `"`

Comment: @p no bro, this is my url http://molugu.com/yantraev/

Comment: @s.kuznetsov that quote is the inline one style=""

Comment: @Crabzon, Then specify the code as it is on your site with the style="" attribute. Because it looks like a typo.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov i tried it here also, its a plain page please check, http://molugu.com/yantraev/test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the font / url within the stylesheet, not try to link it as a stylesheet itself.

For example:

stylesheet.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: BertonVoyageRegular;
  src: url(http://molugu.com/yantraev/BERTON-VOYAGE-TRIAL.TTF);
}


body {
  font-family: 'BertonVoyageRegular',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: @prettyInPink I am genuinely confused...? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: @Crabzon have you tried the code I wrote above within your css stylesheet (amended to your requirements)?